# How to validate if user id in uidb64 format or plain id?

Tags: python, django, django-views, base64

How to check in django view if passed id has uidb64 format or plain integer?

Comment: `'123'.isdigit()` gives `True` while `'12AB'.isdigit()` gives `False`, although this may fail if you are very unlucky (The base64 representation being entirely numeric). What is the use case though? Why not stick with using only _one_ of the options?

Comment: We're making temporary solution for passing uid as a plain id, along with supporting links from old emails for resetting the password. Mail provider fails to process byte64 urlsafe ids. Til they fix it - we need something in between.

Comment: "_Mail provider fails to process byte64 urlsafe ids_" huh? How would a mail provider have problems with that?? (unless for some reason the url is too long?) Isn't that just a url with some ascii characters (don't see why they would have problem with this)?

Comment: "fails to process" means that they converts it to the lower case on their side.